# How do you say "later part" of videos in English?

Tags: word-request

Say, there is a video, at the start part it has sound, at the later part, there is no sound at all.

How do you describe the "later part"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Later part" is a fine term. If you know more precisely, you can say things like "the last third" or "the last 25 minutes" or "starting at the 90 minute mark" or whatever the measurement might be.